# How to pause visualizer for a few secs?

Tags: android

I am recording the sounds using microphone and plotting a visualization based on the visualization, the visualizer goes pretty fast and i can't analyze the data. Is there any way i could pause the visualizer or slow down the visualizer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the debug mode and set break points to step into the function and analyze the data.
 As you know the data is a 1024 byte array. You can check the size using getCaptureSize(),

And whenever you are using getFft() or getWaveForm(), you will be able to see the  individual elements of the array.